# SafeOnRampKit doesn't exist?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm trying to follow the [monerium integration guide](https://docs.safe.global/learn/safe-core/safe-core-account-abstraction-sdk/onramp-kit/integrate-monerium-and-safe), but the example code fails on import of `SafeOnRampKit`. This attribute doesn't seem to exist on `@safe-global/onramp-kit`. My suspicion was confirmed after following the link to [SafeOnRampKit](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/onramp-kit/src/SafeOnRampKit.ts) from the [Onramp Kit docs](https://docs.safe.global/reference/safe-core-sdk/onramp-kit) and getting a 404 from GitHub. Is SafeOnRampKit still supported?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was being refactored at the time this question was asked, but right now the Onramp Kit is publicly available at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/onramp-kit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).